# Запуск activity при закрытии другого приложения

Tags: java, android

можно ли при закрытии другого приложения(при вызове onDestroy, к примеру) или при переходе его в фон, запустить своё activity?
Может быть это можно сделать через широковещательный приёмник или service?

Comment: Можно, если сделать своё приложение оболочкой (Launcher) https://stackoverflow.com/a/73893594/15923106 и уговорить пользователя поставить галку "по-умолчанию", чтобы не запрашивался выбор между вашим приложением и другими оболочками.

Comment: Спасибо, но, думаю, это не то, что мне нужно.

Comment: Ну так надо раскрыть вопрос подробнее - чтобы и мы понимали что вам нужно. "другого приложения" - это какого-то конкретного или любого? Через рут или кастом прошивки решение подходит?...

Comment: Конкретное приложение, идентифицируемое по имени пакета; без рут и прошивок.

Comment: Тогда никак, кроме если вы сами запустили его активность через `startActivityForResult()` и то вы получите только сигнал о завершении этой активности. Или обратный вариант - если второе приложение ваше, вы можете из него послать сигнал о любом событии.

Comment: Спасибо). Мне надо было узнать возможно ли это в принципе. Если бы оба приложения были бы моими, было бы гораздо проще... Но другое приложение не моё